# DC signal detection

Tags: dc

I have a current source that can output different types of waveform depending on the input, including DC (Howland current pump). I need to find a solution as to make sure that when DC is not required it does not appear at the output.

Basically here a series capacitor with the output of the circuit could give me that. It would allow to pass every waveform except for the DC one (when I need DC I could decouple that capacitor).

The problem is that when I attach a resistor as being load my signals could be damaged.

I use 1 Hz frequency, amplitudes from 1 V to let's say 50 Volts with mono and bipolar signals, saw-tooth, triangular signals.

Do you think it helps to place a buffer between the capacitor and the resistor?[image]

This would look like a high pass filter, with cutoff at 1Hz.

Later edit

[image]

Comment: Is R1 part of your circuit or is R1 "the load"?

Comment: Hi, R1 is the load, I need to have a certain current across R1. V1 stands for the current pump's output and I placed the series capacitor to get rid of DC.

Comment: So are you asking for a unity-gain **current** buffer rather than something like a voltage follower? You want the current out of the buffer to be the same as the current in, regardless of voltage?

Comment: I want to have the current i programmed through my current pump across R1 regardless of this safety measure of getting rid of DC component. I was thinking at the high input impedance of an opamp, that's why the buffer

Comment: I just add a pic with my solution, I do not know whether is going to work.

Comment: That will not work, as very little current can flow into the inputs of a standard op amp.

Comment: "The problem is that when I attach a resistor as being load my signals could be damaged." - What exactly do you mean by 'damaged'?

Comment: Actually I got it all wrong, at the output of the current source I would have current, not voltage like it looks above, with the capacitor I should be able to get rid of any DC currents. That input source should have been current type